# How to change the path for spec files

Tags: angular

I am trying to write the test cases for the Angular 2 app from quickstart.

Whenever I run the code, the spec files are always generated in the same folder, but I want to move to a custom testing folder. I am using SystemJS.

For example, `app.component.spec.js` should move to the `testing` folder.

Comment: Have you looked at your `karma.conf.js`? Why don't you want to use the convention?

Comment: I had seen this   
var testBase    = 'testing/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
var testSrcBase = 'testing/';       // test source TS files

How to move those specs.js files in testing folder?
It gives me warning
                                                                                
app/**/*.css" does not match any file.                                                                                
testing/**/*.js.map" does not match any file.

Comment: this warning is just because you don't have .js.map files and .css files, that's all ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I have my test files in `/test`, as well as `karma.conf.js`, and `karma-test-shim.js`.

My directory structure looks like this:
my-project
|--app
|--node_modules
|--test
..    |--app.component.spec.ts
..    |--karma.conf.js
..    |--karma-test-shim.js

Here is what my karma.conf.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'test/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'test/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'test/karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Inside `karma-test-shim.js`, I made a one line change:
`var builtPath = '/base/test/';`

EDIT:
According to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#q-spec-file-location), Google recommends putting the spec test files in the same folder as your components, for the following reasons:

> - Such tests are easy to find
> - You see at a glance if a part of our application lacks tests.
> - Nearby tests can reveal how a part works in context.
> - When you move the source (inevitable), you remember to move
>     the test.
> - When you rename the source file (inevitable), you remember
>     to rename the test file.